# Using the same passphrase for files and filenames with filesystem-level encryption such as eCryptfs

Tags: encryption, file-encryption, file-system

In filesystem-level encryption schemes where files are encrypted and stored individually, 
filenames may or may not be encrypted. [eCryptfs](http://ecryptfs.org/) allows to encrypt filenames with a different key than the one used to encrypt files.

Are there any security benefits to using different keys for file and filenames encryption?